# Evil code from the Python standard library

Tags: python, standard-library

So, we have had this: [The 1000% Speedup, or, the stdlib sucks](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2009/3/1/the-1000-speedup-or-the-stdlib-sucks). It demonstrates a rather bad bug that is probably costing the universe a load of cycles even as we speak. It's fixed now, which is great.

So what parts of the standard library have you noticed to be evil?

I would expect all the responsible people to match up an answer with a bug report (if suitable) and a patch (if superman).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(since this is a different module, placing it in a different answer)

[cgitb](http://docs.python.org/library/cgitb.html) has some weird threading issues.  See [this bug report](http://bugs.python.org/issue1665206).

Answer (score 3):

The [rexec](http://docs.python.org/library/rexec.html) module has so many security holes in it that it's almost useless.

Comment: Rexec is deprecated in version 2.6 and removed in 3.0

Comment: Yes indeed it is.  It's deprecated due to being an evil module.  :-)

Comment: It's been disabled since 2.3.